# Does a multiclassed Hexblade warlock/paladin's Cha modifier stack with their Str or Dex modifier for attack rolls? Or does it replace Str/Dex mods?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, attack, multi-classing, ability-scores

I'm creating a fun villainous figure for my campaign. The choice has fallen on a Paladin-Warlock hybrid. The general idea is to take 2 levels in Paladin for Divine Smite, and then pound 4-5 levels into Hexblade Warlock. Blade-summoning for the flavour, good at all distances, quite mobile, and pretty tanky due to allowed armour-class.

Since Hexblade warlock can use his Cha for attack rolls, will it stack with his Str or Dex modifier depending on the weapon? Or will I have to add my Cha mod *instead of* those stats?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You may choose to use Charisma *instead* of Strength or Dexterity

This is covered in the description of the [Hexblade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheHexblade)’s [Hex Warrior](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#HexWarrior-757) feature (XGtE, p. 55-56):

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. When you attack with that weapon, **you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls.**

It doesn't stack; you choose whether to use Charisma or the usual ability modifier - but not both - for attack and damage rolls with that weapon.

Answer (score 5):

The [Hexblade warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheHexblade)'s [Hex Warrior](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#HexWarrior-757) feature reads (XGtE, p. 55-56):

> When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, **instead of Strength or Dexterity**, for the attack and damage rolls.

So you may add either your Charisma modifier to attack and damage rolls, or your Strength/Dexterity modifiers as appropriate, but not both.